# how to seek a video android ics using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, testing, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, monkeyrunner

I am playing a video `(.mp4 file)` using `monkeyrunner` through the `gallery3d/MovieActivity` component that comes with  the desktop version of `android ics-x86`.

I want to seek(*forward/backward*) using `monkeyrunner`. Is there any way to do it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use key events to seek forward and backward:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD', MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
device.press('KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND', MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
```